# Wordpress language problem

Tags: language

I recently bought a domain. I got the password and username, to logon to the wordpress edit site of the domain. The problem is, that it is in english, and i want it to be danish. Because when you go to the domain/website, it doesn't look good when the two languages are kind of mixed. Now how do i fix this?
I never had wordpress before, so when i downloaded the danish version to my computer, it doesn't effect the domain wordpress :( can I somehow make it effect the site?

I would appreciate your help and answers.

Many thank, Kevin.

Answer (score 2):

Upload your danish language files (da_DK.mo and da_DK.po) in your wp-content/langauges/ folder on your webserver.

Then edit the wp-config.php in your root folder

This

```
define ('WPLANG', '');
```

should be changed in

```
define ('WPLANG', 'da_DK');
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. But how do I go to my webserver? I dont really know what it is :-) hehe

Comment: Your provider should have gave you some FTP login data.
Get any free FTP client like Cyberduck or FileZilla and connect to your server.

Comment: Thaaank you so much :)